# ASP.NET Razor .cshtml file adding an 'if' check like in the controller?

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, razor, actionlink

I have an ASP.NET MVC5 web app. Users can add projects (database entries) and the project also stores the userId of the user that adds a project. I've added the restriction in the controller that won't let other users from deleting or editing your entries, only if it is you.

Here is how it looks in the controller:

```
public ActionResult Edit([Bind(Include = "ProjectId,UserId,Title,ApplicationDeadline,Duration,HourlyRate,TotalProjectCost,City,RequiredPresencePercent,Language,RequiredSkills,Description")] Project project)
        {
            if (ModelState.IsValid)
            {
                if (project.UserId == User.Identity.GetUserId())
                { 
                db.Entry(project).State = EntityState.Modified;
                db.SaveChanges();
                return RedirectToAction("Index");
                }

                return HttpNotFound("Project is not yours!");

            }
            return View(project);
        }
```

but in the View there still is an actionlink

```
 @Html.ActionLink("Edit", "Edit", new {id = item.ProjectId})
```

How can I add a check inside this .cshtml file so the Edit/Delete actionlinks don't even appear near the projects that are not yours?

I've tried `@if (project.UserId == User.Identity.GetUserId())` but of course, `project` is not defined here.

**EDIT: Found the solution thanks to Stephen**

```
 @if(item.UserId == User.Identity.GetUserId())

            {
                @Html.ActionLink("Edit", "Edit", new {id = item.ProjectId})
                @Html.ActionLink("Delete", "Delete", new {id = item.ProjectId})
            }
```

Comment: What is the model for the page? And why project is not defined in the page. If Project was available you can simply wrap  @Html.ActionLink("Edit", "Edit", new {id = item.ProjectId}) with a if statement. I see the Edit action method returns View(Project) what is this view, is this view different from the page you are mentioning.

Comment: : 'IEnumerable<Project>' does not contain a definition for 'project' and no extension method 'project' accepting a first argument of type 'IEnumerable<Project>' could be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?) I think it should be a bit different?

Comment: the model is @model IEnumerable<Leepio.Models.Project>

Comment: `@if(item.UserId == User.Identity.GetUserId()) { .... }`

Comment: thank you @StephenMuecke it worked! thats what I was looking for!:)

Comment: @crystyxn can you please post your answer to make it easier to find

Comment: I edited the original question

Answer (score 0):

Use Model.project like

```
@if(Model.project)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use this:

```
@if(Model.project.UserId == User.Identity.GetUserId()) {
  Html.ActionLink("Edit", "Edit", new {id = item.ProjectId})
}
```